# How to remove or disable windows explorer in Win 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Often when I'm using windows explorer to go after a file or folder, it will 'stop' and then 'restart' on its' own. Of course, this means I have to start my search all over again!  I'm tired of this and have started using XYplorer as my default program. However, once in a while, the windows explorer program will accidentally be used.  Is there a method for uninstalling or disabling it?

Comment: The explorer.exe process is more than just the Windows explorer program. It manages the desktop, start menu, and more.

Comment: If you are consistently having problems with the `explorer.exe` process, there is a problem with your Windows 7 operating system that you shouldn't avoid.  You should probably perform some troubleshooting steps: execute an `sfc /scannow` scan and also scan for malware/viruses.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find it hard to use the system without the explorer.exe running. For example, you'll notice that if you restart the process in Task Manager, the desktop will vanish until it's been restarted completely. Use other apps for file management if you want, but other than that, explorer must remain untouched.